# add class to parent element if conditions are true

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parent, addclass

I am trying to apply a class to a child's parent element if the conditions are true but cannot seem to get it to work. In short, I want to check a table for a cell that is the number "0" and hide its parent row.

I have created a basic jsfiddle of what I have done: http://jsfiddle.net/immbudden/YbZPE/3/

And the snippet of jquery that I have put together:

```
if ($('#the_table>table>td:contains("0")').length === 1) {
    $(this).parent("tr").addClass("hidden");
}
```

I am still learning jQuery and javascript and this is probably something small, but I can't seem to put my finger on it!

Any help would be much obliged, thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: find any cells that have the exact number exactly zero (0) in them and hide their parent row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('td', '#the_table > table').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === '0') {
        $(this).parents("tr").addClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/YbZPE/8/)

Comment: thanks dude, I think yours works best for what I'm trying to do, I just wasn't sure how to write it in relation to the `$(this)`, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use your browser's developer tools!  Or [Get Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

With that page loaded, try this in the javscript console:

```
$('#the_table>table>td:contains("0")')
```

If that gives you

```
[ ]
```

then it's not finding any elements.  Then you can try breaking it down, for example, see if this works:

```
$('#the_table>table>td')
```

And keep taking out and adding bits of that expression until it produces `true` or `false` as you require.

Comment: thanks for the advice dude, I had tried a few things within dev tools and was getting frustrated with it just.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this,

```
$('#the_table table td').filter( function (index) {
    return $(this).text() == '0';
}).parent("tr").addClass("hidden");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YbZPE/5/

Comment: thanks for the input dude, @adeneo 's solution worked best for me with it looping through each. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get teh cell, if you want the first use eq(0):

```
$cell = jQuery('#the_table tr td:eq(0)');
```

then you have to put the class on the parent row:

```
$cell.parent("tr").addClass("hidden");
```

The following code will do it.

```
jQuery('#the_table tr td:eq(0)').parent("tr").addClass("hidden");
```

Comment: thanks for the answer dude, @adeneo got there with the best solution for me, thanks anyway!